# Select test to run with regular expression in sbt

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

I have one module in SBT  (integration tests) with long testing phase. All tests are running for ~20 minutes. I would like to select test to run with regular expression `.*\\.[A-C].*Spec`. In result I want have 4 shorter parallel jobs (on CI server) instead of 1 long.:

- `.*\\.[A-D].*`
- `.*\\.[E-H].*`
- `.*\\.[I-O].*`
- `.*\\.[P-Z].*`

I have checked [sbt testOnly documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#testOnly) and all I can do is use wildcard `*`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is possible right away with `sbt` without writing your own logic to shard your tests and using `testOnly` to execute only a part of them. This could be a solution. Alternatively, there seems to be an `sbt` plugin that aims at doing precisely what you're after: https://github.com/reibitto/sbt-test-shards.

Comment: It looks nice. In ```build.sbt``` have added custom filter:
```def customTestFilter(patterns: Seq[String]): Seq[String => Boolean] = patterns.map { pattern => className: String => className.matches(pattern)}```

and use it in testOnly:
```lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).settings(testOnly / testFilter := customTestFilter)```
In CI I have divided tests to have similar testing time:
```strategy.matrix.tests: [A-I, J-N, O, Q-Z]```
I will try to use sbt-test-shards plugin with custom strategy.